# Export data from Neo4j to jSON

Tags: json, neo4j

I had a csv file of my graph data. I imported this data to Neo4j using the Neo4j plugin available for Gephi. Now, I want this data to be exported as a jSON file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Iirc, Neoclipse can export data from a neo4j db. Unfortunately I wont be able to check this until I get home.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [nice package](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphSON-Reader-and-Writer-Library) that does that in php. The alternative would be to build your own package.

There are also some packages in other languages, in python I found [py2neo](http://py2neo.org/2.0/) which is kind of up-to-date. But Json is not the best way to handle a graph, you may want to take a look at Geoff instead. Py2neo can help with that.